# Twitter Streaming API not working

Tags: twitter-streaming-api

When I try this on terminal:
 `curl https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&track=twitterapi:`

It returns this html document:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to return lots of json data, any thoughts why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "login" with twitter before you can use most of the APIs.

Read [Authentication & Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth).